# PDF Document with XObject jpg Image not displaying in Adobe Reader

Tags: image, pdf, adobe, jpeg

Self-created PDF Document with an XObject Image. When viewing in Adobe Reader, receiving 'An Error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly...' It is not clear exactly what's wrong with the document and wanted to see if anyone had suggestions.

When I run PDF Repair Tool on [www.pdf-online.com](http://www.pdf-online.com) the following errors were reported.

The file is corrupt and cannot be repaired, but possibly recovered
Errors:

3-Heights(TM) PDF repair tool, evaluation license valid until unbounded
Open file.
Analyze Objects.
Analyze Outlines.
Analyze Pages.
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
0x00410518 - I - A path painting operator was used on an empty path.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
***0x8041050F - E - The name Im1 of a xobject resource is unknown.
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF***
0x80410113 - E - The file is corrupt and cannot be repaired. Some of the contents can possibly be recovered.
- Page No.: 1
- File: JDCPDF02_007 (1).PDF
Close file.

The PDF Document contains the following code.

````
% Producer:  
% Created:   20220826084735
% Function:  
% Creator:   
% Author:    
1 0 obj<< /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0>>endobj
3 0 obj<< /Type /Pages /Kids [ 4 0 R] /Count 1>>endobj
4 0 obj<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 792 612 ] /Contents 5 0 R /Resources << /ProcSet 41 0 R /Font << /F1 7 0 R /F2 8 0 R /F3 9 0 R /F4 10 0 R /F5 11 0 R /F6 12 0 R /F7 13 0 R /F8 14 0 R /F9 15 0 R /F10 16 0 R /F11 17 0 R /F12 18 0 R /F13 19 0 R /F14 20 0 R /F15 21 0 R /F16 23 0 R /F17 25 0 R /F18 27 0 R /F19 29 0 R /F20 31 0 R /F21 33 0 R /F22 35 0 R /F23 37 0 R /F24 39 0 R>>>>>>endobj
5 0 obj<< /Length 28756 >>
stream
.
.
.
q 132 0 0 132 45 140 cm /Im1 Do Q 
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image /Width 200 /Height 200 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8 /Filter /ASCII85Decode /Length 48032>>
stream
.
.
.
endstream
endobj
41 0 obj<< /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /XObject << /Image 6 0 R >> >>endobj
7 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Courier /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
8 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Courier-Oblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
9 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F3 /BaseFont /Courier-Bold /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
10 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F4 /BaseFont /Courier-BoldOblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
11 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F5 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
12 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F6 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Oblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
13 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F7 /BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
14 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F8 /BaseFont /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
15 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F9 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
16 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F10 /BaseFont /Times-Italic /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
17 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F11 /BaseFont /Times-Bold /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
18 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F12 /BaseFont /Times-BoldItalic /Encoding /MacRomanEncoding>>endobj
19 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F13 /BaseFont /Symbol>>endobj
20 0 obj<< /Type /Font /Border [0 0 3] /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F14 /BaseFont /ZapfDingbats>>endobj
21 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Helvetica /Name /F15 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 22 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 288 288 360 552 552 888 672 192 336 336 384 576 288 336 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 288 288 576 576 576 552 1008 672 672 720 720 672 600 768 720 288 504 672 552 840 720 768 672 768 720 672 600 720 672 936 672 672 600 288 288 288 456 552 336 552 552 504 552 552 288 552 552 216 216 504 216 840 552 552 552 552 336 504 288 552 504 720 504 504 504 336 264 336 576 696 552 288 216 552 336 1008 552 552 336 1008 672 336 1008 288 288 288 288 216 216 336 336 600 552 1008 336 1008 504 336 936 288 288 672 288 336 552 552 552 552 264 552 336 744 360 552 576 336 744 552 408 552 336 336 336 576 528 288 336 336 360 552 840 840 840 600 672 672 672 672 672 672 1008 720 672 672 672 672 288 288 288 288 720 720 768 768 768 768 768 576 768 720 720 720 720 672 672 600 552 552 552 552 552 552 888 504 552 552 552 552 288 288 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 600 552 552 552 552 504 552 504 ]>>endobj
22 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Helvetica /Ascent 720 /Descent -204 /CapHeight 720 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 24 /XHeight 540 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 32>>endobj
23 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Helvetica /Name /F16 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 24 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 288 288 360 552 552 888 672 192 336 336 384 576 288 336 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 288 288 576 576 576 552 1008 672 672 720 720 672 600 768 720 288 504 672 552 840 720 768 672 768 720 672 600 720 672 936 672 672 600 288 288 288 456 552 336 552 552 504 552 552 288 552 552 216 216 504 216 840 552 552 552 552 336 504 288 552 504 720 504 504 504 336 264 336 576 696 552 288 216 552 336 1008 552 552 336 1008 672 336 1008 288 288 288 288 216 216 336 336 600 552 1008 336 1008 504 336 936 288 288 672 288 336 552 552 552 552 264 552 336 744 360 552 576 336 744 552 408 552 336 336 336 576 528 288 336 336 360 552 840 840 840 600 672 672 672 672 672 672 1008 720 672 672 672 672 288 288 288 288 720 720 768 768 768 768 768 576 768 720 720 720 720 672 672 600 552 552 552 552 552 552 888 504 552 552 552 552 288 288 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 600 552 552 552 552 504 552 504 ]>>endobj
24 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Helvetica /Ascent 720 /Descent -204 /CapHeight 720 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 24 /XHeight 540 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 32>>endobj
25 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Helvetica /Name /F17 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 26 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 288 288 360 552 552 888 672 192 336 336 384 576 288 336 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 288 288 576 576 576 552 1008 672 672 720 720 672 600 768 720 288 504 672 552 840 720 768 672 768 720 672 600 720 672 936 672 672 600 288 288 288 456 552 336 552 552 504 552 552 288 552 552 216 216 504 216 840 552 552 552 552 336 504 288 552 504 720 504 504 504 336 264 336 576 696 552 288 216 552 336 1008 552 552 336 1008 672 336 1008 288 288 288 288 216 216 336 336 600 552 1008 336 1008 504 336 936 288 288 672 288 336 552 552 552 552 264 552 336 744 360 552 576 336 744 552 408 552 336 336 336 576 528 288 336 336 360 552 840 840 840 600 672 672 672 672 672 672 1008 720 672 672 672 672 288 288 288 288 720 720 768 768 768 768 768 576 768 720 720 720 720 672 672 600 552 552 552 552 552 552 888 504 552 552 552 552 288 288 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 600 552 552 552 552 504 552 504 ]>>endobj
26 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Helvetica /Ascent 720 /Descent -204 /CapHeight 720 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 24 /XHeight 540 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 32>>endobj
27 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Helvetica /Name /F18 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 28 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 288 288 360 552 552 888 672 192 336 336 384 576 288 336 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 288 288 576 576 576 552 1008 672 672 720 720 672 600 768 720 288 504 672 552 840 720 768 672 768 720 672 600 720 672 936 672 672 600 288 288 288 456 552 336 552 552 504 552 552 288 552 552 216 216 504 216 840 552 552 552 552 336 504 288 552 504 720 504 504 504 336 264 336 576 696 552 288 216 552 336 1008 552 552 336 1008 672 336 1008 288 288 288 288 216 216 336 336 600 552 1008 336 1008 504 336 936 288 288 672 288 336 552 552 552 552 264 552 336 744 360 552 576 336 744 552 408 552 336 336 336 576 528 288 336 336 360 552 840 840 840 600 672 672 672 672 672 672 1008 720 672 672 672 672 288 288 288 288 720 720 768 768 768 768 768 576 768 720 720 720 720 672 672 600 552 552 552 552 552 552 888 504 552 552 552 552 288 288 288 288 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 552 600 552 552 552 552 504 552 504 ]>>endobj
28 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Helvetica /Ascent 720 /Descent -204 /CapHeight 720 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 24 /XHeight 540 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 32>>endobj
29 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Arial /Name /F19 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 30 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 280 280 360 560 560 893 667 187 333 333 387 587 280 333 280 280 560 560 560 560 560 560 560 560 560 560 280 280 587 587 587 560 1013 667 667 720 720 667 613 773 720 280 493 667 560 827 720 773 667 773 720 667 613 720 667 947 667 667 613 280 280 280 467 560 333 560 560 493 560 560 280 560 560 227 227 493 227 827 560 560 560 560 333 493 280 560 493 720 493 493 493 333 253 333 587 707 560 280 227 560 333 1000 560 560 333 1000 667 333 1000 280 280 280 280 227 227 333 333 600 560 1000 333 1000 493 333 947 280 280 667 280 333 560 560 560 560 253 560 333 733 373 560 587 333 733 547 400 547 333 333 333 573 533 280 333 333 360 560 840 840 840 613 667 667 667 667 667 667 1000 720 667 667 667 667 280 280 280 280 720 720 773 773 773 773 773 587 773 720 720 720 720 667 667 613 560 560 560 560 560 560 893 493 560 560 560 560 280 280 280 280 560 560 560 560 560 560 560 547 613 560 560 560 560 493 560 493 ]>>endobj
30 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Arial /Ascent 733 /Descent -213 /CapHeight 733 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 21 /XHeight 549 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 32>>endobj
31 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Name /F20 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 32 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 253 333 413 493 493 827 773 187 333 333 493 560 253 333 253 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 280 280 560 560 560 440 920 720 667 667 720 613 560 720 720 333 387 720 613 893 720 720 560 720 667 560 613 720 720 947 720 720 613 333 280 333 467 493 333 440 493 440 493 440 333 493 493 280 280 493 280 773 493 493 493 493 333 387 280 493 493 720 493 493 440 480 200 480 547 707 493 253 333 493 440 1000 493 493 333 1000 560 333 893 253 253 253 253 333 333 440 440 600 493 1000 333 973 387 333 720 253 253 720 253 333 493 493 493 493 200 493 333 760 280 493 560 333 760 493 400 547 293 293 333 573 453 253 333 293 307 493 747 747 747 440 720 720 720 720 720 720 893 667 613 613 613 613 333 333 333 333 720 720 720 720 720 720 720 560 720 720 720 720 720 720 560 493 440 440 440 440 440 440 667 440 440 440 440 440 280 280 280 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 547 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 ]>>endobj
32 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Times-Roman /Ascent 693 /Descent -213 /CapHeight 693 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 19 /XHeight 519 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 34>>endobj
33 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Times-Bold /Name /F21 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 34 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 253 333 560 493 493 1000 827 280 333 333 493 573 253 333 253 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 333 333 573 573 573 493 933 720 667 720 720 667 613 773 773 387 493 773 667 947 720 773 613 773 720 560 667 720 720 1000 720 720 667 333 280 333 587 493 333 493 560 440 560 440 333 493 560 280 333 560 280 827 560 493 560 560 440 387 333 560 493 720 493 493 440 400 227 400 520 707 493 253 333 493 493 1000 493 493 333 1000 560 333 1000 253 253 253 253 333 333 493 493 600 493 1000 333 1000 387 333 720 253 253 720 253 333 493 493 493 493 227 493 333 747 293 493 573 333 747 493 400 547 293 293 333 573 533 253 333 293 333 493 747 747 747 493 720 720 720 720 720 720 1000 720 667 667 667 667 387 387 387 387 720 720 773 773 773 773 773 573 773 720 720 720 720 720 613 560 493 493 493 493 493 493 720 440 440 440 440 440 280 280 280 280 493 560 493 493 493 493 493 547 493 560 560 560 560 493 560 493 ]>>endobj
34 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Times-Bold /Ascent 680 /Descent -213 /CapHeight 680 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 19 /XHeight 510 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 262178 /FontWeight 700>>endobj
35 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Times-Italic /Name /F22 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 36 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 253 333 413 493 493 827 773 213 333 333 493 680 253 333 253 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 333 333 680 680 680 493 920 613 613 667 720 613 613 720 720 333 440 667 560 827 667 720 613 720 613 493 560 720 613 827 613 560 560 387 280 387 427 493 333 493 493 440 493 440 280 493 493 280 280 440 280 720 493 493 493 493 387 387 280 493 440 667 440 440 387 400 280 400 547 707 493 253 333 493 560 893 493 493 333 1000 493 333 947 253 253 253 253 333 333 560 560 600 493 893 333 973 387 333 667 253 253 560 253 387 493 493 493 493 280 493 333 760 280 493 680 333 760 493 400 547 293 293 333 573 520 253 333 293 307 493 747 747 747 493 613 613 613 613 613 613 893 667 613 613 613 613 333 333 333 333 720 667 720 720 720 720 720 680 720 720 720 720 720 560 613 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 667 440 440 440 440 440 280 280 280 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 547 493 493 493 493 493 440 493 440 ]>>endobj
36 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Times-Italic /Ascent 693 /Descent -213 /CapHeight 693 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle -15 /MissingWidth 19 /XHeight 519 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 98>>endobj
37 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /Times-BoldItalic /Name /F23 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 38 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 253 387 560 493 493 827 773 280 333 333 493 573 253 333 253 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 333 333 573 573 573 493 827 667 667 667 720 667 667 720 773 387 493 667 613 893 720 720 613 720 667 560 613 720 667 893 667 613 613 333 280 333 573 493 333 493 493 440 493 440 333 493 560 280 280 493 280 773 560 493 493 493 387 387 280 560 440 667 493 440 387 347 227 347 573 707 493 253 333 493 493 1000 493 493 333 1000 560 333 947 253 253 253 253 333 333 493 493 600 493 1000 333 1000 387 333 720 253 253 613 253 387 493 493 493 493 227 493 333 747 267 493 600 333 747 493 400 547 293 293 333 573 493 253 333 293 293 493 747 747 747 493 667 667 667 667 667 667 947 667 667 667 667 667 387 387 387 387 720 720 720 720 720 720 720 573 720 720 720 720 720 613 613 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 720 440 440 440 440 440 280 280 280 280 493 560 493 493 493 493 493 547 493 560 560 560 560 440 493 440 ]>>endobj
38 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Times-BoldItalic /Ascent 680 /Descent -213 /CapHeight 680 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle -15 /MissingWidth 19 /XHeight 510 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 262242 /FontWeight 700>>endobj
39 0 obj<</Type /Font /BaseFont /MICR /Name /F24 /Subtype /TrueType /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /FontDescriptor 40 0 R /FirstChar 32 /LastChar 255 /Widths [ 253 387 560 493 493 827 773 280 333 333 493 573 253 333 253 280 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 333 333 573 573 573 493 827 667 667 667 720 667 667 720 773 387 493 667 613 893 720 720 613 720 667 560 613 720 667 893 667 613 613 333 280 333 573 493 333 493 493 440 493 440 333 493 560 280 280 493 280 773 560 493 493 493 387 387 280 560 440 667 493 440 387 347 227 347 573 707 493 253 333 493 493 1000 493 493 333 1000 560 333 947 253 253 253 253 333 333 493 493 600 493 1000 333 1000 387 333 720 253 253 613 253 387 493 493 493 493 227 493 333 747 267 493 600 333 747 493 400 547 293 293 333 573 493 253 333 293 293 493 747 747 747 493 667 667 667 667 667 667 947 667 667 667 667 667 387 387 387 387 720 720 720 720 720 720 720 573 720 720 720 720 720 613 613 493 493 493 493 493 493 493 720 440 440 440 440 440 280 280 280 280 493 560 493 493 493 493 493 547 493 560 560 560 560 440 493 440 ]>>endobj
40 0 obj<</Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /Times-Roman /Ascent 693 /Descent -213 /CapHeight 693 /StemV 80 /ItalicAngle 0 /MissingWidth 19 /XHeight 519 /FontBBox [0 -300 1000 700] /Flags 34>>endobj
42 0 obj<</Producer(FIS AddVantage Version 2021A)/CreationDate(D:20220826084736)/ModDate(D:20220826084736)/Title(VPI Function EPM Enter Programmers Mode)/Creator(FIS AddVantage Version 2021A User: E1073008)/Author(NCSINT FIS Trust & Custody)>>endobj
xref
0 43
0000000000 65535 f
0000000099 00000 n
0000000162 00000 n
0000000206 00000 n
0000000262 00000 n
0000000668 00000 n
0000029479 00000 n
0000077773 00000 n
0000077893 00000 n
0000078021 00000 n
0000078146 00000 n
0000078279 00000 n
0000078402 00000 n
0000078533 00000 n
0000078661 00000 n
0000078796 00000 n
0000078921 00000 n
0000079048 00000 n
0000079173 00000 n
0000079304 00000 n
0000079397 00000 n
0000079496 00000 n
0000080571 00000 n
0000080767 00000 n
0000081842 00000 n
0000082038 00000 n
0000083113 00000 n
0000083309 00000 n
0000084384 00000 n
0000084580 00000 n
0000085651 00000 n
0000085843 00000 n
0000086916 00000 n
0000087114 00000 n
0000088191 00000 n
0000088408 00000 n
0000089480 00000 n
0000089681 00000 n
0000090760 00000 n
0000090985 00000 n
0000092052 00000 n
0000077678 00000 n
0000092250 00000 n
trailer << /Size 44 /Root 1 0 R /Info 42 0 R >>
startxref
92501
%%EOF```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `/Im1` form  needs to be declared in `XObject` sub-dictionary in the Pages `Resources`. For example:

```
4 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Contents 5 0 R
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 792 612 ]
  /Parent 3 0 R
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F1 7 0 R
      % etc...
      /F9 15 0 R
    >>
    /XObject <<
      /Im1 6 0 R
    >>
    /ProcSet 41 0 R
  >>
>>
endobj
```

Not that well explained in the [PDF IOS-32000 Specification](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf), but mentioned in `Table 33 - Entries in a resource dictionary`.

Also note that your PDF should really start with `%PDF-x.y` e.g. `%PDF-1.4'.

Comment: Indeed, one can not use an image resource if its not mapped to in the resource dictionary. And not only *should* it start with %PDF-x.y, it *must*. If you want to have a PDF file, that is.